# samsung tablet not connecting to my wifi router

Tags: samsung, tablet, router

I have a samsung galaxy tablet. Before 2 days it was connecting to my home wifi router. But now it is not getting connected to the router and it can not find the home wifi network. all other surrounding wifi networks are detected except my home wifi network. I have tried to factory reset many times but still same. need help

Comment: Have you tried using WPS? Also, it may be a router problem. What is your router?

Comment: Did you change the wifi frequency band at your router? Some devices don't support 5 GHz.

Comment: @PediT. is right, and in such cases, the Wi-Fi doesn't show up. So, did you change the settings of the router? Other than that, which Samsung tablet and Android version is it?